# How to enter new line character in message for Amazon Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am creating a bot using Amazon Lex. Currently I am stuck in how to get new line character. My message should look like this:

```
hello my name is X. #New-line
How can I help you?
```

But currently I am getting this:

```
hello my name is X. How can I help you?
```

I have already tried the following thing but it's not working:

```
import os
message='hello my name is X. \n How can I help you?'
```

Comment: See if my answer here helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633654/aws-lex-lambda-return-multiple-lines-with-python/53755169#53755169

Comment: Thank You for the response. Your explanation helped me a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Lex Lambda return multiple lines with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633654/aws-lex-lambda-return-multiple-lines-with-python)

Comment: @JayA.Little Yes, this answers my question. When I integrate my bot with Facebook page, the new line character \n is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Glad that helped. Sorry my second message with the same link was automaticly posted for me when I flagged the question as having already been answered at the link. That way, others know where to look for the answer instead of copying the answer here.